# Disable strict error on OSX in XAMPP

Tags: php, macos, xampp

I have installed one of the last version of XAMPP(1.8.2) into my OSX system with mavericks but I retrieve strict error into my localhost(in other computer works fine).

The problem is the php.ini file.
I have print with phpinfo() the information (some of the information):

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc
Loaded Configuration File   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/php.ini
```

I have copied the path of the php.ini I have tried to modify it into this the configuration error:

```
error_reporting=E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE
```

not works

I have tried to set (a very bad solution)

```
display_errors=Off
```

not works, already strict file enabled.

this is my actual configuration with phpinfo()

```
display_errors  On  Off
    display_startup_errors  On  On
    docref_ext  no value    no value
    docref_root http://php.net/ no value
    enable_dl   Off Off
    enable_post_data_reading    On  On
    error_append_string no value    no value
    error_log   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/logs/php_error_log   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/logs/php_error_log
    error_prepend_string    no value    no value
```

How can I disabled strict error?

Is obvious that every edit of php.ini I have restart the server

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Adding these lines in your PHP code will hide E_STRICT errors:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_STRICT);
```

See my post [Handle PHP errors and exceptions](http://en.open-lamp.com/handle-php-errors-and-exceptions/) for more information.